# Pinpoint cause of sluggish computer

Tags: windows-10, laptop, performance, battery, cpu-usage

I have a brand new Windows 10 laptop. I use it only for mainstream office programs.

Despite top-of-the-line hardware, the laptop feels sluggish. It gets really hot despite sitting idle, and the battery is emptied in just 2 hours (the specs say it should endure 7 hours). So something weird is going on; something stealthy is keeping the computer really busy and I can't tell what it is. I have some friends using the same Windows base image---they are experiencing the same problem.

I've looked in Task Manager (it doesn't report much CPU usage), Battery usage, tried stopping programs... no clue so far.

What can I do to try to pinpoint the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The laptop is defective or infected.

For checking infection, run deep antivirus scans by several
well-known antivirus products.

If no virus is found, the laptop is defective.
As it's new, it's not your job to repair it.

My advice in this case is to return the laptop and ask to be
reimbursed.
If refused, ask for a replacement.
If also refused, ask for repairs.
If refused again, you're in trouble.